# streamline columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I was working for a of couple weeks in building the following:

My dataframe is the following:

[image]

and I would like to build the following:

[image]

I tried with the following but that is not working:

```
formatted_df = pd.melt(dfNull,
                   ["registro"],
                   var_name="Atributo",
                   value_name="Valor")
```

Comment: Please add your data as text so we can copy and paste. Don't post pictures of code/data.

Comment: Please check the description of the tags before using them, tidy in this case it is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem was that "Registro" was capitalized in your DataFrame but not in your melt command.

This seems to work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Registro': [1, 2, 3], 
                   '100 mucho actividad': [None, None, 1],
                   '120 mil conformar': [1, 1, None],
                   '190 solo recibir': [1, 1, 1]})
```

This produces the following DataFrame:

```
            Registro    100 mucho actividad 120 mil conformar    190 solo recibir
0                  1                    NaN               1.0                   1
1                  2                    NaN               1.0                   1
2                  3                    1.0               NaN                   1
```

And now we can melt (I'm using "Registro" as the index of the new DataFrame.) Also note that I'm dropping the NaN columns that result, and sorting the index so that it's in the order you expect.

```
formatted_df = pd.melt(df,
                       ["Registro"],
                       var_name="Atributo",
                       value_name="Valor").dropna().set_index('Registro')

formatted_df.sort_index(inplace=True)

formatted_df
```

Results:

```
                       Atributo     Valor
Registro        
       1      120 mil conformar     1.0
       1       190 solo recibir     1.0
       2      120 mil conformar     1.0
       2       190 solo recibir     1.0
       3    100 mucho actividad     1.0
       3       190 solo recibir     1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the `id_vars` and `value_vars`

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':range(5),'A':range(0,5),'B':['Z','Y','X','W','V']})
>>> df
   ID  A  B
0   0  0  Z
1   1  1  Y
2   2  2  X
3   3  3  W
4   4  4  V
>>> df.melt(id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=['A','B'], var_name='var_name', value_name='val_name')
   ID var_name val_name
0   0        A     0
1   1        A     1
2   2        A     2
3   3        A     3
4   4        A     4
5   0        B     Z
6   1        B     Y
7   2        B     X
8   3        B     W
9   4        B     V
```

Answer (score -1):

Searched the pandas.melt [Pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) link and didn't find the dfNull option
I found a similar code :

```
formatted_df = pd.melt(df,["religion"],var_name="income",value_name="freq")
formatted_df = formatted_df.sort_values(by=["religion"])
formatted_df.head(10)
```

Based on this link [pandas.melt example case](https://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html)

Try and format your code this way to see if the change from "dfNull" to "df" works

```
formatted_df = pd.melt(df,
               ["registro"],
               var_name="Atributo",
               value_name="Valor")
```